# Logged out out of nothing?

Tags: support, bug, login

I googled something, got bunch of SO results, clicked on both (to open a new tab), one tab had me logged in, and in the other I appeared not logged in, and any further page visits showed as not logged in, even here in meta. I logged in again and came to ask this question.

What could have happened? Why was I logged out?

I use Google+ for login if that matters

Comment: Google periodically requires reauthentication.

Comment: @CodeGnome I don't remember reauthenticating ever with StackOverflow as I use it daily. And even, how periodic is that? It's only been a **week** since I've logged in on this PC and I don't think the time passed and some token or something has expired

Comment: I've had the same happen not long ago

Comment: Yeah, this is peculiar.  Let's get some info; are you using Chrome?  Is the account authenticated through Chrome the same account you use for Stack Overflow?  Does anyone else use your computer for Stack Overflow?  Do you periodically clear out your browser's cookies and local storage?

Comment: @Makoto Yes, I use Chrome, the very latest one, and I'm signed in through Chrome, the same account is the same one I use here, nobody else uses my computer, and no, I do not clear those (and I think its the server's responsibility to manage old cookies and such, right?)